# NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied - Getting in in trying to use a D3.csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 coding I have been following tutorials and writing a code.

I have downloaded the D3 library and I am just trying to view a CSV file using this D3 code. but I am getting the error message :

> "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

When I try to execute the code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<title>D3 Example</title>
<script src="/home/yasin/Documents/D3 /lib/d3-3.5.16/d3.min.js">  
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
 d3.csv("/home/yasin/Documents/D3/data.csv", function  
 (myArrayOfObjects){
    myArrayOfObjects.forEach(function (d){
      console.log(d.x + ", " + d.y);
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't put your local file path as URI, many browser restrict the access to local files for security. Run a local Http service or use relative path.

Comment: try adding a period (' . ' ), before the URI. Saying that you have a space after D3 in your HTML, maybe that is causing the problem ? The link may not be correct

Comment: Tried adding a period it did not work but it was the extra space in the D3 folder that was causing the issue removed the space and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link here in your html :

```
<script src="/home/yasin/Documents/D3 /lib/d3-3.5.16/d3.min.js">
```

And here in your D3 :

```
"/home/yasin/Documents/D3/data.csv"
```

Is that extra space your HTML the problem ?

Comment: yes that extra space was the problem I did not realize when I created the folder I gave a space after "D3 " Removed the space from the folder and it started working.

Comment: Ok cool, you can just delete the question if you want as it won't really help anybody (i dont think) or you can select this as the correct one by clicking the tick to the left of the answer :) Up to you